# Futhark dimension mismatch issue

Tags: futhark

I am trying to implement groupby functionality. I have reasoned that my code should be correct.

Here is the important section

```
let type_func (typ: i32) (v1 : u32)  (v2: u32) : u32 =
        match typ
        case 1 -> (*) v1 v2
        case 2 -> (+) v1 v2
        case 3 -> (u32.max) v1 v2
        case 4 -> (u32.min) v1 v2
        case x -> (u32.min) v1 v2 -- TODO change to some panic function


let merge [n][m] (s_cols_t: [n]i32) (a: [m]u32) (b: [m]u32) : [m]u32 =
  map (\i -> if i == 0 then a[i]
                       else (type_func s_cols_t[i-1] a[i] b[i])
      ) (iota m)

let main [n][m][t] (db : [n][m]u32)  (g_col: i32) (s_cols: [t]i32) (t_cols: [t]i32) : [][]u32 =
  let keep_g = db[:, g_col]
  let keep_s_cols = map (\c -> db[:, c]) s_cols
  let keep_inter = concat [keep_g] (keep_s_cols)
  let keep = transpose keep_inter
  let sorted_rows = rsort keep -- ideally pass groupby col here
  let idxs = mk_flags sorted_rows[:, 0]
  let flag = map (== 1) idxs
  let helper = merge t_cols
  in segmented_reduce helper (replicate (length keep_inter) 0)  flag sorted_rows
```

However the compiler throws the following error.

```
[0]> :l groupby.fut
Loading groupby.fut
Error at groupby.fut:63:70-80 :
Cannot apply "segmented_reduce" to "sorted_rows" (invalid type).
Expected: [n][argdim₃₅]u32
Actual:   *[n][ret₁₃]u32

Dimensions "argdim₃₅" and "ret₁₃" do not match.

Note: "argdim₃₅" is value of argument
        length keep_inter
      passed to "replicate" at 63:42-58.

Note: "ret₁₃" is unknown size returned by "concat" at 57:20-48.
```

I have manuelly checked that the dimension of argdim₃₅ and ret₁₃ match by going putting in the code line by line in the REPL. Is this simply a compiler limitation I have encountered or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a hacky fix to the problem. You can put most of the main functionality into another function and then explicitly give the shape of the dimension that is used in the function definition.

```
let groupby [n][m][s][t] (db : [n][m]u32)  (cols: [s]i32)  (t_cols: [t]i32) : [][]u32 =
  let keep_fun columns row = map (\i -> row[i]) columns
  let keep = map (keep_fun cols) db
  let sorted_rows = rsort keep -- ideally pass groupby col here
  let idxs = mk_flags sorted_rows[:, 0]
  let flag = map (== 1) idxs
  let helper = merge t_cols
  in segmented_reduce helper (replicate s 0)  flag sorted_rows

let main db g_col s_cols t_cols =
  let cols = concat [g_col] s_cols
  in groupby db cols t_cols
```

It's an extremely barbaric and ugly solution, but if it works it works.